# California Covid-19 vaccination for non-resident non-citizen

Tags: covid-19, california, vaccinations

Is it possible for a non-resident non-citizen to obtain a Covid-19 vaccination in California (June 2022)? If so how? I can see non-residents may not eligible for a *free* vaccination, but is possible to obtain a paid one?

Comment: I'll try to get details, but a friend of my wife did this - she just made an appointment at a vaccine site and went and got it.  She is non-resident, non-citizen.  I'm unsure if it cost or if she had to provide other information, so I'll try to get the details and post an answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it’s definitely possible. During the initial vaccination wave in 2021 absolutely everyone were allowed to get vaccinated, with absolutely no stipulation on immigration status. My own parents got vaccinated and boosted this way, while simply on a tourist visa.

So just show up for the appointment and you’ll get your shot, no questions asked.

Comment: Just to add a bit of policy to the anecdote, [according to ca.gov](https://covid19.ca.gov/vaccines/#Who-can-get-vaccinated), "Your immigration status does not matter. No one will ask about your immigration status when you get vaccinated."

Answer (score 3):

The State of California doesn't condition COVID-19 vaccine eligibility neither on ability to pay nor on any immigration status. Anyone can make an appointment and be vaccinated.

See [here](https://myturn.ca.gov/en_US/Questions-and-answers.html) for immigration status:

> **Do I have to be a California resident to schedule a COVID-19 vaccine on My Turn?**
>
> No. Scheduling or finding an appointment on My Turn and receiving a COVID-19 vaccine is not based on residency or immigration status.

See [here](https://www.healthforcalifornia.com/blog/covid-19-vaccine) for costs:

> **Can I Get the COVID-19 Vaccine Without Insurance?**
>
> If you’re part of the nearly 8% of Californians that are uninsured, you may worry that lack of insurance will create a barrier to getting the vaccine. A lack of insurance can make affordable health care inaccessible in many instances. Fortunately, that is not the case when it comes to the COVID-19 vaccine. Because the virus is considered a public health crisis, special measures have been put in place to ensure all people can get the vaccine.